# How to select time intervals with zero values

Tags: sql, datetime, join, group-by, intervals

I need to select time intervals with no (0) data. How to to this in SQL?

Example:

```
Time Data
10:00 0
10:15 0
10:30 1
10:45 0
11:00 12
11:15 0
11:30 0
11:45 0
12:00 7
```

Result:

```
10:00 - 10:30
10:45 - 11:00
11:15 - 12:00
```

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: All three intervals listed in the expected result include `0`. Perhaps you mean something else, e.g. intervals delimited by `1`?

Comment: My DBMS is MS SQL,  i need time interval from time when first 0 accure to time when first data accure (including it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to identify the groups and then aggregate based on the group.

A simple way is to count the number of non-zero values on or after each value.  This brings in the ending time:

```
select min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when data > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp
having min(data) = 0
order by min(time);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/15794) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note:  This uses window/analytic functions which are standard SQL supported by most databases.

Comment: Thanks! That's what i looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMSes support *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select time, data,
      -- assign a new group number whenever it's not a zero
      -- = same number for a value and following zeroes
      sum(case when data = 0 then 0 else 1 end) 
          over (order by time desc -- start from the latest row
                rows unbounded preceding) as grp 
   from myTable
 ) 
select
   min(time), max(time)
from cte
group by 
   grp -- aggregate previous zeroes with the non-zero row
```